# Javascript call on jquery load / post

Tags: jquery, html

My problem doesn't concern Ajax purposes, but javascript initialisations.

When we use `$(element).load(...)`, how could I automatically update all the loaded elements to create - for example - a rangeInput element from a input type text ?

What I'm searching is a trigger like `$(button).onClik()` for `load()` and `post()` functions.

Comment: not getting you ...you want to create dynamic element

Comment: Not understand your question

Comment: If i understand what you mean, you want to apply plugin to loaded elements? But as `load()` is shorthand for both onload event and ajax request, not sure what you mean. Provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue, with all relevant code

Comment: Yes A. Wolff, but without use the callback of $(...).load or $.post function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use global ajax event as [ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/):

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Comment: I think that's the solution i were wanting for !
Thanks A Wolff !

Comment: Nope Pranay, your answer is a good one too, but with this solution i can't do a `load()` or a `post()` without the `commonfunction` (in your example)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this by using jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

```
$( element).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

---

for each load you can create common function and call it

```
$( element).load( "ajax/test.html", 
  commonfunction
);

var commonfunction = function  ( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i know this possibility but i need to duplicate the code everywhere i'll need to do that

Comment: hum.. In fact, i would call some code at each `load()` or `post()` call, without put the code in the callback like your answer

Comment: @MattewPhoenyxEon - create common function as in asnwer